# prove integrable functions by means of Holder inequality

Tags: integration, holder-inequality

Let $a(t)$ be a positive continuously differentiable function. In addition, it is well known that $a(t)$ is bounded and $\int_{0}^{\infty}a(t)dt$ is bounded. I am goint to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}a(t)^mdt$ (where $m\geq1$)is integrable by means of Holder inequality. If this claim is not true, please help me to find counterexample.

Comment: If $a(t) \leq M$ then $\int (a(t))^{m}dt \leq M^{m-1} \int a(t)dt <\infty$.

Comment: $a(t)=t^2+1$ is a positive continuously differentiable function. It is however not well known to be bounded!